# Penthao Kettle Download File from URL

Tags: http, pentaho

I want to download a File from a URL. (ex. http://www.webadress.com/service/servicedata?ID=xxxxxx)

I found the HTTP Step for Job executables but I am forced to define a Target file name instead of just accepting the filename the Webdownload offers. (ex. ServiceData20200101.PDF)

Other Problem is that it creates a File even when the Webcall actually wouldn't supply a File.
Is the REST Client or HTTP client Step in Transformations able to download a file over a URL call that accepts the File as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP steps in Pentaho are somewhat limited. In similar use cases in the past I've done this by using an external shell script with arguments that then calls wget or curl and saves the result. Then Pentaho picks up the file in the temp dir and processes it from there.

The Shell job step allows you to specify a script file and pass fields from the stream as arguments.

Note that if you paste shell commands directly into the step on the second tab, they will execute in the embedded shell with older versions of curl and wget. You will also be missing environment config and certificates/keys.